# A Maple equivalent for Matlab's input function

Tags: matlab, maple

I'm new to Maple, and I do really need the Matlab's input() function there. I searched a lot but there was no easy way or at least a straightforward way like Matlab to get inputs.
Actually what I need is a way to get function definitions from user in Maple.
I'd be happy if somebody helps :)

E.g.(Matlab code)

```
f = input("Enter your function : ");
```

Output :

> > Enter your function : x^2 + y^2 + log(10) + 2*exp(z)

What I'm asking is how can I implement something like this Matlab code in Maple ?

Comment: I don't really know anything about Maple, but [this page](http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3907040) implies that is has support for `scanf` to some degree.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the [readstat](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=readstat) command? Eg,

```
restart:

f := readstat("Enter your function:");
```

A more sophisticated popup could be devised from [Maplets](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Maplets) code. As a simple example with Maplets,

```
restart:

maplet:=Maplets:-Elements:-Maplet(
      Maplets:-Elements:-InputDialog["ID1"](
         "Enter your function:",
         ':-onapprove'=Maplets:-Elements:-Shutdown(["ID1"]),
         ':-oncancel'=Maplets:-Elements:-Shutdown())):

f:=parse(Maplets:-Display(maplet)[]);
```

You didn't say how your end-user was otherwise going to interact with the session. Will the user run the whole worksheet? Have you considered making an entire interactive assembly with [Embedded Components](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=EmbeddedComponents)?

Comment: Thank you, It seems that I have to use f:=unapply(f,x,y,...) after readstat(), right ? Is there any way or easier way to avoid this stage ?

Comment: You can enter an operator like `x->x^2-x-1` when answering `readstat`, or an expression like `x^2-x-1`. How to turn an expression into an operator should be asked as a whole other question, in a new thread, because it has nothing inherently to do with readstat, scanf, or the question you asked above. You could do it simply, eg. `f:=unapply(readstat("enter an expression in x:"),x);` or you can ask in a new thread how to get fancy and make it use `indets` to robustly determine the indeterminate name with which to unapply, etc.